# Where can I find SHA256/SHA512 hashes for SpringBoot packages?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, dependency-management

I'm trying to improve the security of my Gradle project by making use of its [dependency verification](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_verification.html) feature.

Out of the box, Gradle can generate hashes for each of my declared dependencies, but the docs suggest that I explicitly specify hashes provided by the developer if at all possible.

I've been looking around the Springboot website, docs, and GitHub repository, but I can't find a place where these hashes are documented. Are they available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring Boot team doesn't appear to publish SHA-256 nor SHA-512 currently. For example, here are the contents for various projects:

- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.4.3/
- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.4.3/
- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/2.4.3/

Only SHA-1 can be found.